# Superheavy assisted trip to Mars

Tags: spacex, mars, spacex-starship, spacex-super-heavy

i just had a thought and wonder about feasability, cost and possible implications.

What I assume is the plan:
A Superheavy pushes Starship into Orbit. Cargo Starships follow and refuel. Fueled up Starship accelerates towards Mars and takes 3 Months to get there.

My idea:
Assuming Superheavy can reach Orbit(thought train could end here):
Join fueled up Starship with refueled Superheavy in Orbit for high speed trip to Mars.
A secon Superheavy would join (boosted by a third?) to eat the gained Speed.

I hope I can be understood.

**Possible?
Time saved?
Cost?**

Comment: Not sure how you intend to get Superheavy to orbit.

Comment: thanks, so I assume that is the issue:)
I thought  that if instead of a load it only lifts itself, it might get further